# How to fix broken synaptic updates: "Package is in a very bad inconsistent state"

Tags: ubuntu, aptitude

I have a Dell Mini9 running Ubuntu 8.10.  One day I had the bright idea to see if I could install a LAMP stack.  I had trouble installing MySQL 5.0.  I don't recall the error, but ever since all attempts to run update-manager, synaptic, or apt-get fails with an error about mysql-server-5.0: "Package is in a very bad inconsistent state".

I've tried `apt-get remove mysql-server-5.0` and also `install` but with no luck.  Both fail with the same error below.  How can I fix this?

```
$ sudo apt-get remove mysql-server-5.0
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  dhcdbd libisc32
Use 'apt-get autoremove' to remove them.
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  mysql-server-5.0
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 1 to remove and 164 not upgraded.
1 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 85.4MB disk space will be freed.
Do you want to continue [Y/n]? 
dpkg: error processing mysql-server-5.0 (--remove):
 Package is in a very bad inconsistent state - you should
 reinstall it before attempting a removal.
Errors were encountered while processing:
 mysql-server-5.0
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Comment: Consider using <pre> for screen output where syntax highlighting is not needed.

Answer (score 20):

None of the other answers worked for me on Maverick.

In my case, I found this worked:

```
sudo rm /var/lib/dpkg/info/flashplugin-nonfree.prerm

sudo dpkg --remove --force-remove-reinstreq flashplugin-nonfree
```

(replacing "flashplugin-nonfree" with the name of the broken package, and replacing "prerm" with the type of script that failed - in my case it was "postrm", the post-removal script.)

And they say Ubuntu is easy to use!! *grumble grumble*

Comment: --purge is better to drop broken deps

Comment: I've been searching for hours for a solution to a similar problem, and this is the only one that worked.  Thankyou.

Answer (score 6):

I had the exact same issue with a mysql install. You need to *purge* the packge. Simply removing a package does not remove the config files that came with it.

Also, I'm going to refer to **mysql-server-5.0**, but realize that there's a wrapper package **mysql-server** that always points to the latest version. i.e. if you ask to install **mysql-server**, *apt-get* should tell you that it depends on **mysql-server-5.0** and install both. If you have the **mysql-server** package on the system, you should make sure that's gone too before you attempt to reinstall.

- Make sure the mysql server (mysqld) isn't running. If it is, bring it down:

  > sudo /etc/init.d/mysqld stop
- Check if any packages depend on mysql-server-5.0:

  > sudo apt-cache rdepends mysql-server-5.0

  If they do, you'll need to use the *--force* option to uninstall.
- Purge the package (include the *--force* option, depending on #2)

  > sudo apt-get --purge remove --force mysql-server-5.0
- Make sure the installer files are also cleared by running

  > sudo apt-get autoclean 
  >  
  >   sudo apt-get autoremove
- Install the server package again

  > sudo apt-get install mysql-server-5.0

This should hopefully fix your problem. However, the package might still be broken, *if* you made any changes to files that came from the **mysql-common** package.

**mysql-common** is the base package used by both client and server components. If things aren't working still, try re-installing this package. There will definitely be packages that depend on this; check using #2 above. Purge **mysql-server** before reinstalling **mysql-common**. Also, do not forget to reinstall **mysql-common**, else your system will be very broken.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to give `aptitude` a try, which has better handling of dependencies:

```
sudo aptitude remove mysql-server-5.0
```

Comment: The error here is `dpkg`'s, so I don't think `aptitude` would necessarily fare any better. Don't get me wrong, I'm all for `aptitude` over `apt-get`, but at the end of the day, they both hand the real nitty-gritty over to `dpkg` (which you'll be happy to hear was originally implemented in Perl).

Comment: ;-) I just thought it might be worth a try.

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem with mailman.
Deleted /etc/init.d/mailman with

```
rm /etc/init.d/mailman
```

fixed it :)

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
sudo dpkg -i reconfigure mysql-server-5.0
sudo apt-get remove --force mysql-server-5.0
```

If its another package that is broken, try `apt-get remove --force` that package as well.

Answer (score 0):

The `dpkg` error that you have there suggests that the problem occurs when `dpkg` is trying to actually remove the package. (At the end of the day, `apt-get` and `Synaptic` and the like hand off the actual work to `dpkg`.)

Have you tried doing exactly what the message says and *re*-installing first?

`apt-get install --reinstall mysql-server-5.0`

As silly as it might sound, if `dpkg` is choking during the removal process (because some file it's supposed to remove has gone missing in the interim) then reinstalling and *then* removing can sometimes help. Make sure that `mysql` is not running before you try to install it or remove it, as [nagul suggests](https://superuser.com/questions/22110/how-to-fix-broken-synaptic-updates-package-is-in-a-very-bad-inconsistent-state/22177#22177).

Answer (score 0):

`dpkg -r --force-remove-reinstreq <package>` removes a package without checking if it requires reinstallation.

After that you should be able to reinstall the package with your preferred package manager.